# Get a SELECT result with column comments

Tags: mysql

I have various tables with data that have important comments on the columns. I want to get a SELECT result not only with column names in the header, but also with comments.

```
column_name1|column_name2|...
column_comment1|column_comment2|...
column_data1(1)|column_data2(1)|...
column_data1(2)|column_data2(2)|...
column_data1(i)|column_data2(i)|...
.
.
.
```

I tried to extract comments like...

```
SELECT column_comment FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` as columns
    WHERE
        table_name = 'mytable'
```

but found no way to transpose the results into columns for subsequent 
`UNION with SELECT * FROM mytable data`

UPDATE
I have a table mytable

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | name  | address                              |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | John  | ...                                  |
| 2    | Lissy | ...                                  |
| 3    | Elis  | ...                                  |
| 4    | Jack  | ...                                  |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Columns have comments:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'a name comment',
  `date` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'an address comment',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`))
```

I want to see something like:

```
+------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | name            | address                              |
+------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
|      | a name comment  | an address comment                   |
+------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | John            | ...                                  |
| 2    | Lissy           | ...                                  |
| 3    | Elis            | ...                                  |
| 4    | Jack            | ...                                  |
+------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are actually asking here. Can you have another go at the question, maybe with some better examples

Comment: I want a normal SELECT result that contains comments on the columns for each column. I know how to extract separate comments for columns and separate SELECT. The question is how to combine them later in a common query. The problem is that the comments are extracted as one column and the data as rows. 
I don't understand what column comments serve at all, if it's difficult to extract them later using the normal SELECT.

Comment: maybe with some better examples

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you in advance for answering.

Comment: Ahhhhh now I see what you are trying to do. Never would have thought of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may use below dynamic query -

```
set @sql = null;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when column_name = ''',
      column_name,
      ''' then column_comment end) as ', 
      column_name)
  )  into @sql
FROM
(
  select column_name
  FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` as columns
    WHERE table_name = 'T'
)d;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',  @sql, ' FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = ''T'' union all select * from T');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f932478b1ee9b0ac262f5abb819dd306) is the fiddle.

Comment: Beautiful solution!
Thank you very much for the answer. 
The only thing worth clarifying is that Distinct is not needed in this case, as it breaks the order of the lines.

Comment: @o_nerti, You are most welcome. I am happy I was able to help you.